# Saving numpy into a text file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Trying to save numpy into a new txt file. I've got the amount, average, min and max. I'm now trying to save those numbers into a new txt file. I'm new to numpy and python, so this might be an easy question.

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    x = np.loadtxt("wind_readings.txt")
    print("There are", len(x), "")
    print('Average:', np.average(x))
    print('Max:', np.amax(x))
    print('Min:', np.amin(x))

main()
```

I want the new txt file to have this format:

Amount:

Average:

Max:

Min:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
file = open("testfile.txt","w") 
file.write(f"Amount: {len(x)}\n")
file.write(f"Average: {np.average(x)}\n")
file.write(f"Max: {np.amax(x)}\n")
file.write(f"Min: {np.amin(x)}\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify what the format I want it to be in. I've changed the question now.

Comment: Is it possible to get it to write the amount, average etc on separate lines?

Comment: Yes sorry just noticed that. Edited the answer

Comment: Thank you so much!